# What is the use case for Service Account impersonation in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What exactly is the goal of allowing for impersonation of Service Accounts in Google Cloud Platform? Can someone give example scenarios where this can be useful or needed?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/impersonating-users-with-google-cloud-platform-service-accounts-ba762db09092 "This is a common use case in a service-based architecture: services will perform actions (eg. store a record, retrieve a blob) on behalf of users."

Comment: @ceejayoz that article talkes about the inverse(that is impersonating a user with a service account)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service accounts are a special Google account (not attached to a user) that is associated with either an application or VM that does not require end user authentication.

The impersonation goal is to give the permission to a user to use a service account and grant access to those service accounts permissions without granting them directly to the user.

Impersonating service accounts is useful in scenarios where you need to grant short-term access to a specific resource.

Examples:
you have a bucket of important data that is typically read-only and want to temporarily grant write access through a trusted service accounts.

Other examples at the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) about impersonate service accounts.

Comment: But couldn't you achieve that via Roles? You give the role to the user and later remove it? Even for a service account, you'd have to do the same after the user has achieved their task right?

Comment: Yes, you can, maybe in small projects with few resources and users can work, but it is not a good practice. Impersonation allows you to treat a SA as a resource that you can assign to multiple users, so this way users (internal or external) can have access to a specific resource or application and this way they can work together. 
For example: you have a long running job that your employees have permissions to start. You don't want that job to be terminated when the employee who last started that job leaves the company.